# R: dbplyr using eval()

Tags: r, dplyr, dbplyr

I have a question on how to use `eval(parse(text=...))` in `dbplyr` SQL translation.
The following code works exactly what I want with `dplyr` using `eval(parse(text=eval_text))`

```
selected_col <- c("wt", "drat")

text <- paste(selected_col, ">3")

implode <- function(..., sep='|') {
  paste(..., collapse=sep)
}

eval_text <- implode(text)

mtcars %>% dplyr::filter(eval(parse(text=eval_text)))
```

But when I put it into the database it returns an error message. I am looking for any solution that allows me to dynamically set the column names and filter with the `or` operator.

```
db <- tbl(con, "mtcars") %>%
     dplyr::filter(eval(parse(eval_text)))

db <- collect(db)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right approach, but dbplyr tends to work better with something that can receive the `!!` operator ('bang-bang' operator). At one point dplyr had `*_` versions of functions (e.g. `filter_`) that accepted text inputs. This is now done using NSE (non-standard evaluation).

A couple of references: [shiptech](https://shipt.tech/https-shipt-tech-advanced-programming-and-non-standard-evaluation-with-dplyr-e043f89deb3d) and [r-bloggers](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/07/bang-bang-how-to-program-with-dplyr/) (sorry couldn't find the official dplyr reference).

For your purposes you should find the following works:

```r
library(rlang)
df %>% dplyr::filter(!!parse_expr(eval_text))
```

Full working:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(dbplyr)
library(rlang)
data(mtcars)
df = tbl_lazy(mtcars, con = simulate_mssql()) # simulated database connection

implode <- function(..., sep='|') { paste(..., collapse=sep) }

selected_col <- c("wt", "drat")
text <- paste(selected_col, ">3")
eval_text <- implode(text)

df %>% dplyr::filter(eval(parse(eval_text))) # returns clearly wrong SQL

df %>% dplyr::filter(!!parse_expr(eval_text)) # returns valid & correct SQL

df %>% dplyr::filter(!!!parse_exprs(text)) # passes filters as a list --> AND (instead of OR)
```